# Visual Studio 2010 Publish Profiles -- Where are they stored?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, publish, profile

We have set up a few Publish Profiles that are used to deploy web apps to various servers, and it all works great with 1-click deployment.

However, we find that even though the entire solution is under source control (SVN), the profiles do not seem to be carried over, so we need to re-create the profiles on each developer's machine manually.

It seems that since the profiles exist only for the solution currently loaded, that they must be stored in the solution files somewhere. But they do not carry over when someone else does an update to pull down the code.

I'm guessing that whatever file they are in is one that we aren't covering in the source control project, but I haven't been able to figure out which one.

Someone must know where the Publish Profiles are stored. Is there any way to copy them from machine-to-machine so that we don't have to retype them for each developer?

Comment: More annoying that I have to recreate publishing profile even for different workspace, but the same project

Answer (score 37):

The file name is actually going to be $(ProjectName).Publish.xml, and should be in the same folder as your .csproj file. If you enable the "Show All Files" option in Solution Explorer it will appear, and you can include it in your project from there. That will get it into source control.

One thing to be careful of: VS won't auto-check-out this file if you attempt to change and save the profile settings, but it won't throw an error either. There's a warning in one of the Output windows about it, if you pay attention; otherwise it will just look like it's ignoring your changes.

Comment: _VS won't auto-check-out this file_  This is really annoying, this prevents us from being able to share that publish file via TFS among team members and branches.  If anyone has a suggestion for how we might do this, I'm all ears.

Comment: I just make sure to remind all our devs to check it out themselves before changing the publish profiles. It's annoying, true, but definitely not a show-stopper. You could also report it to MS Connect and they might fix it in a future version.

Comment: You can also just uncheck the readonly filesystem bit if you want to manage independent publish profiles, but still have a common base managed in SCM.

Comment: It seems that the publish file holds the last publish date of each file to speed up publishing, at least for filesystem deploy. Checking these changes into source control would create churn if you deploy often. I believe that's the reasoning behind the no-auto-checkout behavior.

Comment: what about setting up a pre-build function that runs tf checkin $(ProjectName).Publish.xml and then tf checkout $(ProjectName).Publish.xml. that will make sure the file is constantly checked out and saved

Comment: Super helpful answer! I'd been trying to figure out why none of my publish profiles were staying saved—every time I returned to the project in VS, they were gone—and it's because my changes weren't getting into source control, of course!

Comment: On my Visual Studio 2010 install for a Web Site project, these files are under App_Date\PublishProfiles.

Comment: Microsoft believes hiding this file and preventing its checkout protects you from yourself. This is really a workaround their horrible security architecture.

Answer (score 18):

In the interest of keeping SO up to date, as of VS2012 (or [VS2010 with Azure SDK 1.7+](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/06/15/visual-studio-2010-web-publish-updates.aspx)) publish profiles are now stored at `Properties\PublishProfiles\$(ProfileName).pubxml` for Web Applications and `App_Data\PublishProfiles\$(ProfileName).pubxml` for Websites.

They are also now MSBuild files and are expected to define properties as documented [How to: Edit Deployment Settings in Publish Profile (.pubxml) Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398069.aspx#publish_profile_file)

Comment: And this... [Cloning visual studio 2012 publishing profiles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696038/cloning-visual-studio-2012-publishing-profiles)

Answer (score 1):

The reason I had this problem was due to `.user` files: I noticed the settings were being saved in `Properties/PublishProfiles/$(ProfileName).pubxml` but the actual credentials needed for deployment were saved in `.user` files that were being excluded from source control.

Answer (score 0):

On my Visual Studio 2010 install for a Web Site project, these files are under App_Date\PublishProfiles.