# Cloning Visual Studio 2012 publishing profiles

Tags: visual-studio

How do I copy a visual studio publishing profile?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The only solution I found is to copy/paste/rename the publish settings file (.pubxml) in the `Properties\PublishProfiles` directory.

When you create a new publish profile, two files are created : .pubxml and .pubxml.user. The .pubxml.user file contains only a few settings that apply to a specific user, such as an encrypted password.

Comment: I was afraid it'd be something so user unfriendly

Comment: yes, but the new file will immediately be available in VS (no restart) and you can put it in source control.

Answer (score -1):

Once you choose Publish Website it opens with the Preview Tab highlighted. Click the Profile link on the left and then choose the drop down box (I know what you're thinking.... there's only one) choose  and you can set up additional profiles.